# How can i push array of strings in redux reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have used a reducer which stores the ipfs hashes as an array. I  can't push array of values rather than that the existing hash is overwritten by the new hashes. The Reducer code is

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    fetching : false,
    fetched : false,
    ipfsHash : [],
    error : null
}
export default (state=INITIAL_STATE,action) =>{
        switch(action.type){
            case 'FILE_UPLOAD_START':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching:true
                }
            case 'FILE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching : false,
                    fetched : true,
                    ipfsHash : action.payload // IPFS is replaced rather than pushing into the array
                }
            case 'FILE_UPLOAD_ERROR':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching : false,
                    fetched : false,
                    error : action.payload
                }
            default:
                return {...state}
        }
    }
```

Any Idea for pushing the hashes into the array ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use spread operator

```
return {
  ...state,
  fetching : false,
  fetched : true,
  ipfsHash : [...state.ipfsHash, ...action.payload]
}
```

or `concat`

```
return {
  ...state,
  fetching : false,
  fetched : true,
  ipfsHash : state.ipfsHash.concat(action.payload)
}
```